# improper integral on open and closed interval

Tags: analysis

improper integralable on an open interval (0,a]

Generally improper integral if f is integrable, but |f| is not integrable.

if f is improper integrable (0,100], then is |f| integrable on (0,1]?

I think it is not true, but

but I can't find a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a singularity outside $[0,1]$ but not in this interval, then $|f|$ is integrable on $(0,1]$  Example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$.